# Extracting two strings from a string using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I'm trying to extract two string from a string. The format of the string is as follows:

```
$text = 'First string here(second here)';
```

The seconds string will always be at the end within quotes. I'm trying to extract them efficiently. I've tried using this: `preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text, $match)` and `preg_match('/\(([^\)]+)\)/', $text, $match)`

The above expressions work fine, but I'm trying to do it in one go, not separately. I guess it's my OCD kicking in :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capture groups:

```
$text = 'First string here(second here)';
if (preg_match('#^([^\(]+)\(([^\)]+)\)$#', $text, $match)) {
    print "$match[1]\n";
    print "$match[2]";
}
```

[See demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/GcBjv9).

Answer (score 0):

```
$out= preg_split('/[\(\)]/',$text)[1];
```

Comment: That works perfectly, but how do I remove the parenthesis from the seconds string?

Comment: minor thing but I'd include the [`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) flag ([example](http://ideone.com/2DvsiU)).